# Extracting a cpio file on intel edison

Tags: yocto, intel-edison

I am trying to extract the content of a cpio file using the command:

```
cpio -idv < filename.cpio
```

to the directory where I currently are.

It works perfectly on Ubuntu with the same file, but on the Intel Edison nothing is happening. There is not even an error message appear.
Does anybody know how to extract a cpio file on the Intel Edison running on a yocto kernel?

I have not downloaded any new packages for the Edison could this help the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the GNU cpio or BusyBox? Generally BusyBox features a more limited set of flags compared to its GNU equivalents.